# AWS S3 Sync function - missing files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am transferring files from an S3 bucket to an EC2 instance.

Using the AWS CLI, I can see that there are 219 files of ~43GB total size in the S3 bucket in question

```
[IN]
    aws s3api list-objects --bucket resultsdata --output json --query "[sum(Contents[].Size), length(Contents[])]"

[OUT]

[
    43367899797,
    219
]
```

I have been using the [AWS S3 sync command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html) to transfer the files from the bucket to the EC2 machine.

When I run this I successfully see the downloading of the individual files within the bucket. However - it appears to end prematurly.

```
Completed 706 of 1550 part(s) with 36 file(s) remaining
```

When I go to the download location and carry out a count of files

```
ind /home/ec2-user -type f | wc -l
```

I get 198 files and not 219.

I have run the AWS sync command multiple times

```
aws s3 sync s3://MYBUCKETNAME .
```

What am I missing?

Edit

I have ruled out there being duplications in the S3 bucket

Edit 2

Deleting the files from ec2 and trying to use cp -

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket . --recursive
```

I get

```
Completed 4286 of 5084 part(s) with 34 file(s) remaining
```

But - when I count the files I get a different number again, 186.

So sync gives me 198, cp gives me 186. Both are short of the 219 files in the S3 bucket. Anyone?!

Comment: Do you know if it is including folders? While folders don't really exist in S3, sometimes there are zero-byte files created as placeholders. By the way, I love the [sum(Contents)] thing -- I never knew this was possible!

Comment: A good point! But, I have found the actual culprit. I had no disk space left! I think S3 should really tell me that as an error message...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had no space left on the device!

I would have expected an error message in this case. A new mounted volume has solved the issue